# How can one find this limit?

Tags: limits

It's given that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}(f(x)^2-6f(x))=-9$$.

How can one figure out  $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}f(x)?$$

Excuse me, if this is too easy.

Comment: Let $f$ be continuous at $x=2$. The fist limit gives you a polynomial of degree 2 in the variable $f(2)$. Solve it and...

Comment: @Avitus You can't assume such a thing.

Comment: You're missing a parantheses. HALP

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 2} (f^2(x)-6f(x)+9)=0\iff\lim_{x\to 2} (f(x)-3)^2=0$$

Comment: I've reached that point. I'm not sure why this leads to the conclusion that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}f(x)=3$

Comment: Remember that $x^{2}$ is a continuous function, so $0 = \lim_{x\to2}\left(f\left(x\right)-3\right)^{2} = \left(\lim_{x\to2}f\left(x\right)-3\right)^{2}$. What can you conclude from this?

Comment: @Matheo    Because $\lim_{x\to 2} (f(x)-3)^2=(\lim_{x\to 2} (f(x)-3))^2=0<=>\lim_{x\to 2} (f(x)-3)=0=>\lim_{x\to 2} f(x)-\lim_{x\to 2} 3=0<=>\lim_{x\to 2} f(x)=\lim_{x\to 2} 3=3$

Comment: @Brian Scholl. Isn't it more important that $\sqrt{x}$ is a continuous function on $[0, \infty)$ and therefore if $\lim\limits_{y \to 2} y^2 = z$ then $\lim\limits_{y \to 2} \sqrt{y^2} = \sqrt{z}$... Wondering for my own interest.

Comment: Oh, I get it, so $\lim\limits_{y \to 2} y = \lim\limits_{y \to 2} y $ and $x^2$ is continuous, therefore $\lim\limits_{y \to 2} y^2 = (\lim\limits_{y \to 2} y)^2 $... Cool

Comment: @mdenton8 In this case, we only need the continuity of $x^{2}$ because $x^{2} = 0 \iff x = 0$. So, when you see that $\left(\lim_{x\to2}f\left(x\right)-3\right)^{2} = 0$ you can then conclude that $\lim_{x\to2}\left(f\left(x\right)-3\right) = 0$ and reach the conclusion from there.

Comment: @mdenton8, it's more than that. It works the other way too, but only at one point.

Comment: Thanks @Mitsos. Is this solution acceptable when we don't know whether the limit of the function exists?

Comment: @Matheo, if you mean the $\lim f(x)$ there is no problem. All we need to know is that $\lim_{x\to 2} (f(x)-3)^2$ exists.